# What is the "long form" of asm()?

Tags: c, assembly

It is well known that asm() is a way to put assembly code into c code, but it is said in some resource that "unless you use the 'long form' of asm(), which correctly declares to the compiler the C-language effects of your assembly code, you leave yourself open to the substantial risk that a different compiler version, different compilation flags, or even minor changes to your C code may have disastrous interference effects." I want to know what is the "long form" of asm()?

Comment: It's called [Extended Assembly](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "long form" most likely refers to [GNU Extended Asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm), where the user can specify constraints, input, output registers, as well as a clobber list to help the optimizing compiler in register allocation.

Answer (score 3):

All use of embedded assembly code is subject to compiler specific details.  Including any such long form.  There isn't a standard for that sort of thing.